# Is NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate 'ChangeUpdate' behavior broken?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

The docs for NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate provide the following sample code

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

    }

}
```

When I create a new NSManagedObject, **NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert** fires (great!). When I change the value of an attribute (used for the cell's title), the **NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate** fires. Unfortunately, the new title doesn't automatically display unless I reload the table, section or row. Indeed, if the new name causes the result set to sort differently, then **NSFetchedResultsChangeMove** fires and all is well since the provided code reloads the entire section.

UITableView has a method *reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation* so I tried using this under the **NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate** code block. It does indeed work ... but the docs for this specific method read as though I don't need it (notice the last line):

> Reloading a row causes the
>   table view to ask its data source for
>   a new cell for that row. The table
>   animates that new cell in as it
>   animates the old row out. Call this
>   method if you want to alert the user
>   that the value of a cell is changing.
>   If, however, notifying the user is not
>   important—that is, you just want to
>   change the value that a cell is
>   displaying—you can get the cell for a
>   particular row and set its new value.

And yes, if I log what is happening, when

```
[self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

gets invoked on an **NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate**, it is able to retrieve the latest 'name' value and set it in the cell's textLabel. The name is just not rendering in the cell unless I reload it. Even if I simply click the cell the name shows up. Note that to recreate this behavior, you must create a new managed object and then give it a name that causes it to sort FIRST in the NSFetchedResultsController. That way, the NSFetchedResultsChangeMove doesn't fire (which does work since it reloads the section).

Am I missing something or is this expected behavior? The 'discussion' for *reloadRowsAtIndexPaths* leads me to believe I should be able to simply set the cell's textLabel without reloading the row, section or table.

Comment: This should be working. I'm doing the same thing. For changes to attributes, when save: is called, the MOC notifications go out. NSFetchedResultsController sees the change and calls my configureCell:atIndexPath method. There I grab the values and fill the cell, and the cell is updated immediately. Post your configureCell code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `[cell setNeedsLayout]` or/and `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` to cause the cell to get refreshed, depending on your cell's implementation.

If you compose the cell of subviews as we usually do, you rely on `- layoutSubviews`, so you should call `[cell setNeedsLayout]`.

If you draw the cell directly with `– drawRect:`, you should call `[cell setNeedsDisplay]`.

If you use both composition and drawing, you should call both.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that you do not need to reload the cell in order to have the changes take place, you have to remember that the iPhone caches view drawing as much as possible.  Once you have newly configured your cell, you need to call setNeedsDisplay on the cell in order to trigger the redraw.

Comment: At this point - what is the best way to get the cell that is on the screen? tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: creates a new cell whereas I want to get a reference to the cell on-screen ... right?

Comment: Normally, there's no need, for any cell that you're configuring, you can call setNeedsDisplay.  If it's a new cell, it doesn't have a cache, so no worries, if you're reconfiguring, it will redraw.  If you really want to know which screens are visible, however, take a look at my response to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996515/getting-visible-cell-from-uitableview-pagingenabled/1566432#1566432

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not been explicitly stated, you've actually got to make sure that you include the delegate methods for controllerWillChangeContent: and controllerDidChangeContent:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
```

and

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(BSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    @try {
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"caught exception: %@: %@", [e name], [e description]);
    }
    @finally { }
}
```

The NSFRC can fire off multiple controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath: methods during any one change, so don't expect the table row to update straight after each one of those. They'll only update after you call endUpdates on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the UI updating logic **in MAIN Thread** solved my issue (both `[cell setNeedsLayout]` & `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` not works for me):

```
...
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
    });
    break;
...
```

---

What's more (not about this issue, but will be useful), you'd better choose to use the `newIndexPath` if it's available:

```
...
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      NSIndexPath * targetIndexPath = (newIndexPath ?: indexPath)
      [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:targetIndexPath]
              atIndexPath:targetIndexPath];
    });
    break;
...
```

Comment: those events are already on the main thread, what you are doing is shunting to the next event loop, although GCD is not 100% good at that, perform after delay is more reliable.