# How to determine if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, scroll

How can I determine if the user has scrolled to the last cell/bottom of a UITableView?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, and scroll view exposes a `contentOffset` property (documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset)).

Use this with a bit of math to determine if the contentOffset is within `frame.size.height` of the bottom.

Update:  here's a stab at a formula that will give you what you want:

```
if(tableView.contentOffset.y >= (tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height)) {
  //user has scrolled to the bottom
}
```

Comment: Code is almost there! I can detect the bottom, but when I get to the bottom the code in the if block gets called many times if the user holds the scroll position. How can I resolve?

Comment: Maybe you could add a timer when scrolling, invalidate any current timer, and once the timer fires (say after 250ms) then you could execute your code.

Without more details it's very hard to suggest the right thing though.

Comment: put this code in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating, this will insure that it only fires once instead of many times

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSArray *paths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];`. Then check if the last object in that array is the indexPath for the final cell.

Source: [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996515/getting-visible-cell-from-uitableview-pagingenabled/1566432#1566432)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to newer iOS versions, there's an easy way with the willDisplayCell function:

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, willDisplayCell cell:UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) {

       if (indexPath.row >= tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)) {

           NSLog("User got to bottom of table")

       } 
}
```

Note that UICollectionViews have a similar function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Comment: This will be called when the elements were inserted, and table automatically scrolled without user interactions.