# Content offset of NSCollectionView

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I'm working with `NSCollectionView` and want to implant paging logic (loading additional content). For that I want to know when user have scrolled to bottom of collection view, because I used to add this approach in iOS apps. How I can do that? Or maybe I need to work with `NSScrollView` or `NSClipView`?

Comment: why not detect using indexPath ? in your cellForItemAtIdexPath ?

Comment: Because collection view calls `cellForItemAtIdexPath` in advance of max offset

Comment: See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160642/how-to-determine-if-the-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom-of-the-uitableview) may be.

Comment: `NSCollectionView` doesn't inherit from `UIScrollView` and doesn't have `contentOffset` property.

Comment: The `contentOffset` property just returns `bounds.origin`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CollectioView have ScrollView delegate method.

Try this:

```
var lastOffsetY: CGFloat = 0

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y == (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        loadMore()
    }
}
```