# Deleting UITableCells programmatically without animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When I programmatically delete a bunch of cells (I am normally at the bottom of the tableview)  there is a move around of all the cells (as the ones being deleted are from the top). How can I stop this moving / jerking / rearranging when I delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `reloadData` over adding and removing rows, and it'll all just snap.

Comment: How'd you mean? Change the datasource and not do the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths business?

Comment: Right. Change the datasource and then `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: Wow, sweet wish Id asked this 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the method you're looking for (?) :

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPath withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

Before calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths, save the indexPath of the row that is currently visible. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996515/getting-visible-cell-from-uitableview-pagingenabled) on how to do that.

Once you have the indexPath saved, after your rows are deleted, call [this method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:):

```
[tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:savedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```